# In iOS, how to find where in the code a particular button is located?

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging

I'm running an app in the emulator and am somehow getting the generic error message "Error - Try Again" shown below.

In order to debug this, I would like to locate the `UIView` corresponding to the "Error" button. Previously, I've worked on the backend for a React Native app and there was the Inspector (cf. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging) with which you could locate React elements in the code.

As far as I can tell from the Help -> Simulator Help menu (see below), there is no such functionality for iOS, or am I missing something?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature you're looking for is not officially supported by apple, but there's an awesome tool named [Sherlock](https://sherlock.inspiredcode.io/) that enables such functionality on iOS simulator.

It injects itself into the iOS Simulator so that it can monitor views and adjust them in real time and lets you jump into the file related to the view you want to from the simulator.
You can inspect any app in the simulator, including system apps and dynamically change their UI elements!